# Rails 6.0 action text couldn't find file 'trix/dist/trix' with type 'text/css'

Tags: r, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actiontext

So I am using rails 6.0.1 and trying to use Action text.
So I run the command `rails action_text:install`
and add the gem image_processing
and finally run rails db:migrate

When I launch my app I got this error message:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Hotels#index
Showing /myapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

couldn't find file 'trix/dist/trix' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths: 
  /myapp/app/assets/config
  /myapp/app/assets/images
  /myapp/app/assets/javascripts
  /myapp/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/cloudinary-1.13.1/vendor/assets/html
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/cloudinary-1.13.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.5.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.5.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.5.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/formtastic-3.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.1/lib/assets/compiled
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /myapp/node_modules
```

under assets/config/stylesheets/actiontext.scss I have:
`//= require trix/dist/trix`
 and config/initiliazers/assets.rb:
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')`

Any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 22):

I actually find the solution.
I had to run 
`yarn install --check-files`
then reinstall action_text:
`rails action_text:install`
and then it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. I followed it through, encountered nothing that looked like an error, but I still get the same error message. Do you have any other ideas on this?

Comment: @AndreasGebhard Had the same problem, and I've resolved it adding `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')` in config/initializers/assets.rb, then doing the action proposed by @chris

Answer (score 3):

The issue arises while setting up your Rails 6 app for the first time on your PC. You need to install the JS dependencies. Run these lines of code

```
bundle install
yarn install --check-files
rails action_text:install
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error in my CI pipeline in Github Actions, with a Rails 7 app. The above solutions did not help. It turned out I needed to add yarn builds to my action:

```yaml
# .github/workflows/verify.yml

      - name: Compile assets
        run: |
          yarn build
          yarn build:css
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering this issue in Rails 7, it is because of the change made in Rails 7 where the `yarn install` step before precompiling assets was removed in https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43641.

To maintain the same behaviour as rails 6. Add following.

```rb
Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance ["yarn:install"]
```